# Lyapunov function candidate and Global asymptotic stability

Tags: control-theory, lyapunov-functions

The following second order system is given:

$\dot{x}_1 = -2x_1^3 + 2x_2^2x_1$

$\dot{x}_2 = x_1^2x_2 - 2x_2^3$

I want to determine whether the origin is globally asymptotically stable or not. For this, I need to construct a Lyapunov function. I tried $V(x) = 0.5x_1^2 + 0.5x_2^2$ but cannot prove that $\dot{V}(x) < 0$. What is the ideal Lyapunov function for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the quadratic function you have suggested. Then, we have that the derivative of the Lyapunov function along the flow of the system is given by

$$
\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x}f(x)=-2x_1^4+3x_1^2x_2^2-2x_2^4.
$$
This can be rewritten as
$$
\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x}f(x)=\begin{bmatrix}x_1^2\\x_2^2\end{bmatrix}^T\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 3/2\\3/2 & -2\end{bmatrix}}_{\mbox{$M$}}\begin{bmatrix}x_1^2\\x_2^2\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The fact is that the matrix is not positive definite, however this does not consider the fact that the vector $(x_1^2,x_2^2)$ is always nonnegative. We need to look at something called strict copositivity, which is luckily simple to establish in the 2-dimensional case.

A 2-by-2 matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$ is strictly copositive if and only if $a_{11},a_{22}>0$ and $a_{12}+\sqrt{a_{11}a_{22}}>0$. Applying this formula to the matrix $-M$ yields that the matrix $-M$ is indeed copositive and that

$$\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x}f(x)<0\mathrm{\ for\ all\ }x\ne0$$

which proves the global asymptotic stability of the zero-equilibrium point of the system.

Edit. In fact, we can say more and without using the concept of copositivity. Start with

$$
\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x}f(x)=-2x_1^4+3x_1^2x_2^2-2x_2^4.
$$
and let $y_1=x_1^2$ and $y_2=x_2^2$, which yields the polynomial

$$
P(y_1,y_2):=-2y_1^2-2y_2^2+3y_1y_2.
$$

Now pick the polar coordinates $y_1=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y_2=r\sin(\theta)$ where $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$ and $r\ge0$. This yields

$$
P(y_1,y_2)=r^2(-2+3\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))=r^2(-2+\frac{3}{2}\sin(2\theta))\le -r^2/2.
$$

This implies that
$$
\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x}f(x)\le-\dfrac{1}{2}(x_1^4+x_2^4)\le-2V(x)^2.
$$

This then implies that
$$
V(x(t))\le \dfrac{V(x(0))}{1+2tV(x(0))}
$$